# PUIS - Power Up In Standby - correct useage for HDD windows 10

Tags: windows, hard-drive, sata, uefi

I am currently reconfiging a windows 10 pc. Some of the drives have jumpers for PUIS

This would work great for me to keep power and heat down when not needed and to stop all the drives booting up at once. Definitely some of the drives would not be needed often at all.

Whats the best way to get this going? Is it plug and go with the jumper setting, does the UEFI let windows know the drive is there and will windows be able to spin it up first time its needed?

I've just done a test, with an un-formatted drive. Set the jumper. Turned on. Drive stays off. Nothing showing in Windows - so far so good.

Of course, the drive us unallocated, so going into Disk Management, not there either... and doesn't spin up either - which makes me think windows doesn't know its there, or cant "call" it, or see it until it spins.

Can it identify itself through sata interface - whether spinning or not?

Ill format etc in due course when I'm ready for the drive, but does anyone know if there are any specific steps I need, or a driver or service needed for windows to manage such disks?

It is a UEFI system with GPT SATA drive. Intel DX58S0 motherboard.